# IRremote.h "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, arduino

**I am working on Mac**

Coming from JS and almost exclusively web development, I have no idea what's going on here.

I've gotten in to hardware programming as a hobby, and caught on to the basics pretty easily. However, I recently started a project involving an IR receiver, and needed to install the [IRremote](http://z3t0.github.io/Arduino-IRremote/) library.

I have moved the downloaded "IRremote" folder into the library directory as the installation said.

When I run the sample test code provided

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}
```

the error `No such file or directory` shows up every time.

This may be the most blatantly obvious question I've ever asked, but I'm a beginner when it comes to stuff like this. Thank you!

Comment: Does your filename contain space(s) ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the path.  You could try `#include <IRremote/IRremote.h>` or something similar where you give the path to the file. 
 Also, when you use `<` and `>` around the name in the `#include` command it looks in the system library directories.  If you didn't put the files there then they won't be found.  If you want to specify a file relative to the source you should use regular double quotes: `#include "IRremote/IRremote.h"`  If you tell us the actual path where you put the downloaded folder and the actual path of your source we might figure it out.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The path to the file is `~/Library/z3t0-Arduino-IRremote-2dc97b2/IRremote.h`

Comment: @fassn it does not

Comment: Then if the library folder is in the path (I don't know if it is on Mac), you should include : `<z3t0-Arduino-IRremote-2dc97b2/Irremote.h>`

Comment: When the site says "Move the 'IRremote' folder that has been extracted to your libraries directory." and then the next step says "Make sure to delete Arduino_Root/libraries/RobotIRremote Where Arduino_Root refers to the install directory of Arduino" I imagine that they mean "Move the 'IRremote' folder that has been extracted to your Arduino_Root/libraries directory Where Arduino_Root refers to the install directory of Arduino" but I could be wrong.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I completely missed that it could be the arduino library instead of the system library. I'll check really quick

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Success! If you post an answer below I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have to change the include line in the end or did it work fine when the library was placed in the correct location?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah All I needed to do was change the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions at https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote says (emphasis is mine):

> ## Installation
>
> 1. Navigate to the Releases page.
> 2. Download the latest release.
> 3. Extract the zip file
> 4. Move the "IRremote" folder that has been extracted to **your libraries directory**.
> 5. Make sure to delete Arduino_Root/libraries/RobotIRremote. Where Arduino_Root refers to the install directory of Arduino. The library RobotIRremote has similar definitions to IRremote and causes errors.

That bolded bit is completely vague and could refer to many different places.  The description in the line below it does a good job of describing where the "libraries directory" actually is but the description is not on the line where it is needed.

I think when they say

> 4. Move the "IRremote" folder that has been extracted to your libraries directory.

they actually mean

> 4. Move the "IRremote" folder that has been extracted to Arduino_Root/libraries/IRremote where Arduino_Root refers to the install directory of Arduino.

Comment: I have raised an issue on the project to try to get the wording fixed: https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/issues/636